# Having trouble using the PRINT function when wanting to apply it to a text with a lot of words

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

When ever I try to print it is very hard to do as only a little bit of it is applied to the PRINT function. Is there an easier way to print a text with a lot of words?

```
    sentence= ("A Turing machine is a device that manipulates symbols on a strip of tape
according to a table of rules. Despite its simplicity, a Turing machine can be
adapted to simulate the logic of any computer algorithm, and is particularly
useful in explaining the functions of a CPU inside a computer. The "Turing"
machine was described by Alan Turing in 1936, who called it an
"a(utomatic)-machine". The Turing machine is not intended as a practical
computing technology, but rather as a hypothetical device representing a
computing machine. Turing machines help computer scientists understand
the limits of mechanical computation.")
    sent_count=0
    word_count=sentence.split()


    numberofwords=len(word_count)
    for ch in sentence:
        if ch== ".":
           sent_count +=1

    print(sentence)
    print("There are",numberofwords, "words in this paragraph.
```

")
    print("There are",sent_count,"sentences in this paragraph.")

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding this. "`as only a little bit of it is applied to the PRINT function`" > A little bit of what?

Comment: The coloring applied to your code should give you a huge hint about what's going on...

Answer (score 2):

You're enclosing the string in double quotes, but the string contains double quotes, so Python doesn't know where it ends. Escape them with backslashes: `"this is \"a\" string"`, or enclose the string with a quote type (single/double) it doesn't contain: `'this is "a" string'`, or enclose the string with triple quotes: `'''this won't fail'''` or `"""this "won't" fail"""`.